# GitLab push error: LFS objects are missing

Tags: git, gitlab, git-lfs

I've used Git LFS for GitLab for a few months now without any problems, but it returned the following error while pushing files lately:

```
$ git push origin master
Git LFS: (14 of 14 files) 8.88 MB / 8.88 MB
Counting objects: 54, done.
Delta compression using up to 6 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (49/49), done.
Writing objects: 100% (54/54), 5.42 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 54 (delta 15), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: GitLab: LFS objects are missing. Ensure LFS is properly set up or try a manual "git lfs push --all".
To https://gitlab.com/<gitURL>.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.com/<gitURL>.git'
```

where `gitURL` is my git-repository URL.

As the error suggests I tried to manually push my binary files, using `git lfs push --all`, which gives me the following output:

```
$ git lfs push --all origin master
Git LFS: (0 of 0 files, 1370 skipped) 0 B / 0 B, 1.77 GB skipped
```

which means by my understanding that all my local files are already successfully stored on my server.

Trying to fetch all lfs files does work fine as well:

```
$ git lfs fetch --all
Scanning for all objects ever referenced...
* 1446 objects found
Fetching objects...
```

which finishes without any errors.

Moreover checking all lfs files for consistency using `git lfs fsck` seems to work fine too:

```
$ git lfs fsck
Git LFS fsck OK
```

I'm starting to run out of ideas about fixing this error now. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This happened to our repositories on GitLab when they introduced their own LFS support recently. If you want to continue to use your own LFS then the process is rather painful - you need to disable their own LFS support on each repository, but there doesn't seem to be a web option for it, you need to do it via their command line API:

1. Install the python gitlab command line API: `pip install python-gitlab`
2. Setup a private gitlab token for your account, generate it on the Access Tokens portion of your account profile.
3. Write a configuration file out to `~/.python-gitlab.cfg`:

   ```
   [global]
   default = yourrepo
   ssl_verify = true
   timeout = 20

   [yourrepo]
   url = https://gitlab.com/
   private_token = <your API key from the settings tab on gitlab.com>
   ```
4. Grab your gitlab project id from the top of the settings web page
5. `gitlab project update --lfs-enabled false --id <Your project id>`

Some of our developers reported that even this didn't work and they had to resort to sending a manual HTTP PUT request to `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<Your project id>?lfs_enabled=false` with a Private-Token header set to your private token. For example, with CURL:

```
 curl -X PUT --header "Private-Token: <private token>" -F "lfs_enabled=false" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project id>
```

Comment: I don't understand this answer.  What does "their own LFS" and "your own LFS"?  And why remove LFS on gitlab?  What is this answer fixing?

Comment: Historically, GitLab didn't offer LFS support, so many people will have their own solutions setup on their repos. This answer allows you to turn of the new GitLab LFS support and continue using your own.

Comment: There is now a GUI setting available. Under the project settings -> General -> Permissions -> Git Large File Storage. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/#sharing-and-permissions

Comment: Disabling "Git Large File Storage" helped me get rid of this problem. Thank you tech4him.

Answer (score 12):

I got this error even though (to my knowledge) I did not have any LFS objects in my gitlab repository.

```
remote: GitLab: LFS objects are missing. Ensure LFS is properly set up or try a manual "git lfs push --all".
```

The solution was to disable **Git Large File Storage (LFS)** in the gitlab project settings.

Settings > General > Visibility, project features, permissions > Expand > Git Large File Storage (LFS)

Answer (score 8):

This command helped me:

```sh
git lfs ls-files -l | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs git lfs push --object-id origin
```

And it is faster than the other answer.

Comment: Worked for me. Also needed: `git config lfs.contenttype false`